# Service is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an error while using AngularJS, I can't import a Service from one module to another. I have a Service called MenuDataService in module Data, that I want to use in module MenuApp, and when I try to do it, it gives an error with the following link https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=MenuDataServiceProvider%20%3C-%20MenuDataService%20%3C-%20CategoriesController.

src/data-module/data.module.js:

```
angular.module('Data', []);
```

src/data-module/menudata.service.js:

```
angular.module('Data')
.constant('CATEGORIES_URI', 'some_uri')
.service('MenuDataService ', MenuDataService);

MenuDataService.$inject = ['$http', 'CATEGORIES_URI'];
function MenuDataService($http, CATEGORIES_URI) {
  var service = this;

  service.getAllCategories = function () {
    return httpRequest(CATEGORIES_URI);
  };
};
```

src/menuapp-module/menuapp.module.js:

```
angular.module('MenuApp', ['Data']);
```

src/menuapp-module/categories.controller.js:

```
angular.module('MenuApp')
.controller('CategoriesController', CategoriesController);

CategoriesController.$inject = ['MenuDataService'];
function CategoriesController(MenuDataService) {
  console.log('CATEGORIES CONTROLLER');
};
```

index.html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/data-module/data.module.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/data-module/menudata.service.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/menuapp-module/menuapp.module.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/menuapp-module/categories.controller.js"></script>
```

Any help would be great since I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Thank you very much!

Comment: what is the error...

Comment: It gives a link in the error, which is the following https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=MenuDataServiceProvider%20%3C-%20MenuDataService%20%3C-%20CategoriesController

Comment: You MIGHT need to do data.MenuDataService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra space in the service name that you define.

```
.service('MenuDataService ', MenuDataService);
                         ^
```